# Laravel : Problem using bootstrap locally

Tags: php, html, css, laravel, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having problem using bootstrap locally, if i use bootstrap like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

it will load very quick, however when i downloaded bootstrap and use it locally on the public folder like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

I get an error of "Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded", the folder was placed correctly in "public/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css", how to fix this?

This is my index.php

```
<?php

/**
 * Laravel - A PHP Framework For Web Artisans
 *
 * @package  Laravel
 * @author   Taylor Otwell <taylor@laravel.com>
 */

define('LARAVEL_START', microtime(true));

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register The Auto Loader
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Composer provides a convenient, automatically generated class loader for
| our application. We just need to utilize it! We'll simply require it
| into the script here so that we don't have to worry about manual
| loading any of our classes later on. It feels great to relax.
|
*/

require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Turn On The Lights
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| We need to illuminate PHP development, so let us turn on the lights.
| This bootstraps the framework and gets it ready for use, then it
| will load up this application so that we can run it and send
| the responses back to the browser and delight our users.
|
*/

$app = require_once __DIR__ . '/../bootstrap/app.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Run The Application
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Once we have the application, we can handle the incoming request
| through the kernel, and send the associated response back to
| the client's browser allowing them to enjoy the creative
| and wonderful application we have prepared for them.
|
*/

$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);

$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
);

$response->send();

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

Comment: Why not use the CDN version for your local site?

Comment: Greetings @LeeTaylor, i would like to use it locally without the need of internet connection.

Comment: Where is your index file located ? Try to use developer tool to find the style sheet path is correct or not

Comment: Greetings @raaahad, it is located in the public folder.

Comment: `<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">` try to add local style file

Comment: Do you get any error messages on the dev tools console?

Comment: Greetings @Laisender, there is no error message in the console, but the webpage says "Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Error\FatalError
Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded"

Comment: Try with this e.g. `http://localhost/projectroot/public/assets/style.css` => `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('assets/style.css') }}">`

Comment: Well, do you run any computation heavy threads in your application? If not, 60 seconds exceeded points to an infinite loop or something like that.

Comment: And when you change it back to the CDN the error immediately disapears?

Comment: @raaahad i tried `href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css"` and it is now working, but what would be the cause of timeout using `href="{{ asset('bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}"`, also will there any problem if i don't use the "asset" command on href if i pushed my website online?

Comment: Have you downloaded compiled css file? Try to download with php artisan

Comment: You definitely used the asset command in the right way as far as I see. As long as you don't have changed the default behaviour of `asset()` in your `.env` and config files.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing it with npm and compiling it with Laravel Mix. Its very easy to do.

In your console

```bash
npm install bootstrap
npm update
```

In your `/resources/js/app.js`

```
import 'bootstrap';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

And finally, in your `/resources/views/layout.blade.php`

```html
<script src="{{ asset('/js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

Now, we can compile the script like so:

```
npm run dev
```

Worked for me on the first try.